# the number 0.23571113....

Tags: limits, prime-numbers, real-numbers, irrational-numbers

So I was looking into infinite decimals that have patterns and trying to practice turning them into ratios
(for example 0.1111...=1/9)

and then I thought of this number 0.23571113... with all the primes into infinity
I think this number has a name probably related to Euler, if so I would like to know it.

my question is this number rational or irrational or hasn't been figured out yet?
if so please provide simple proof.

Comment: The [Copeland–Erdős constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copeland%E2%80%93Erd%C5%91s_constant) is irrational If it were rational, its decimal expansion would eventually be periodic

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/778695/prove-the-irrationality-of-0-235711131719

Comment: It is irrational.  See [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/914367/does-the-string-of-prime-numbers-contain-all-natural-numbers?noredirect=1&lq=1).  As the concatenation of all prime numbers contains within it every natural number, your decimal expansion will never repeat.

Comment: @JMoravitz how can we be sure that it *does* contain every natural number in it?

Comment: @PrimeMover that is explained in the linked post.

Comment: @JMoravitz oh yes, thanks.